# How did they develop this website footer?

Tags: javascript, css

I understand how to show/hide DIV but how did they make this footer?

I would love this on my website.

Please take a look at this page it's Constant Contact by the way, notice the footer.

[Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp)
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here is a very simplistic version of how to achieve something similar to your example. You only need to use JavaScript if you're using a browser < IE7, otherwise simple CSS can do it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TN8up/)**

```
#footer{
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the div a fixed position. something like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; position:fixed; bottom:0px; background-color:blue; height: 50px;">
Excellent footer content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they used jQuery to animate the div that contains all the footer content.

The relevant .js file is here: http://www.constantcontact.com/_script/social-media-toolbar.js?version=1307033023000

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the posts, I simply thought this was cool! I will bookmark this post for the future.